# computing the product $\prod_{n=1}^{2016} \frac{2^{2^{n-1}}+1}{2^{2^{n-1}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products

how can i calculate the product: $\prod_{n=1}^{2016} \frac{2^{2^{n-1}}+1}{2^{2^{n-1}}}$?

I can see that in the denominator it's a geometric series, but in the numerator i can't see how to simplify.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Write $\frac{2^{2^{n-1}}+1}{2^{2^{n-1}}}$ as $1+ \frac{1}{2^{2^{n-1}}}$

Comment: Have you tried to see a pattern in the first few factors of the expansion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem!

You can write this as : $\prod_{n=1}^{2016} \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{2^{2^{n-1}}} \right )$

If we write $\frac12$ as $a$, then the problem is $$\prod_{n=1}^{2016} \left ( 1 + a^{2^{n-1}} \right )$$
If you observe carefully, every term of the form $a^k$ occurs exactly once in the above product for all $0 \leq k \leq {2^{2016}-1}$. 
Think of the product as $(a^0 + a^{2^0})(a^0 +a^{2^1})(a^0 + a^{2^2})(a^0+a^{2^3})...$. Then for any number $1 \leq k < 2^{2016}$, consider its binary representation. If the $i^{th}$ bit is $1$, then, for $a^k$ choose $a^{2^i}$ from the corresponding bracket, else choose $a^0$ from that bracket. Hence, every number of the form $a^k$ can be seen to occurs exactly once in the above expression. As for $a^0$, just choose $a^0$ from all the brackets.

Thus, it is effectively a geometric progression. $$\therefore \prod_{n=1}^{2016} \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{2^{2^{n-1}}} \right ) = \frac{1-\frac1{2^{2^{2016}}}}{1-\frac12} = 2 - \frac{2}{2^{2^{2016}}}$$

Comment: i didn't understand the geometric progression part. how did you calculate? did you do sum of geometric progression?

Comment: Yes, I did the sum of geometric progression. The product $\prod_{n=1}^{2016} \left ( 1 + a^{2^{n-1}} \right )$ is equivalent to $1 + a + a^2 + ... + a^{2^{2016}-1}$. Hence the geometric progression.

Comment: yes but what did you do with the $+1$ in the product before this summation?

Comment: Which  $+1$ are you talking about? $\textbf{1}+a+a^2+...$ this $1$?

Comment: this one $\prod_{n=1}^{2016} \left ( \textbf{1} + a^{2^{n-1}} \right )$

Comment: it's a product not a sum that's what i don't understand.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: i tried to understand but i didn't get the binary part. can it be done by simple algebra from this part: $(a^0 + a^{2^0})(a^0 +a^{2^1})(a^0 + a^{2^2})(a^0+a^{2^3})...$?

Comment: Every number $k$ can be written in the form $a_02^0 + a_12^1+a_22^2+...$ where $a_i = 0$ or $1$ for all $i$ and this representation is unique for every $k$. Thus, $a^k$ comes exactly once in the product for all k.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\prod_{n=1}^{2016} \frac{2^{2^{n-1}}+1}{2^{2^{n-1}}}&
=\frac{(2^{2^{0}}-1)(2^{2^{0}}+1)\cdots (2^{2^{2015}}+1)}{(2^{2^{0}}-1)2^{2^{0}}\cdots 2^{2^{2015}}}\\
&
=\frac{(2^{2^{1}}-1)(2^{2^{1}}+1)\cdots (2^{2^{2015}}+1)}{(2^{2^{0}}-1)2^{2^{0}+\cdots +2^{2015}}}\\
&
=\frac{(2^{2^{2}}-1)(2^{2^{2}}+1)\cdots (2^{2^{2015}}+1)}{2^{2^{0}+\cdots +2^{2015}}}\\
&
\cdots\\
&
=\frac{2^{2^{2016}}-1}{2^{2^{2016}-1}}
\end{align*}

Comment: how did you get that simplification of $2^{2^{n-1}}+1$  in the beginning?

Comment: It's no simplyfied...

Comment: how does the third row is equal to the first two rows? the first term there is $15$.

Comment: $(2^{2^0}-1)(2^{2^0}+1)=2^{2^1}-1$ and so on...

Comment: but $(2^{2^2}-1)(2^{2^2}+1)=2^{2^3}-1$ and the product starts from $3...$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=2^{(2^n)}+1$ be the $n$-th Fermat number. Since:
$$ a_n-2 = 2^{2^n}-1 = \left(2^{2^{n-1}}-1\right)\cdot \left(2^{2^{n-1}}+1\right)\tag{1} $$
we get, by induction,
$$ \prod_{n=0}^{N} a_n = a_{N+1}-2 \tag{2} $$
hence:
$$ \prod_{n=1}^{2016}\frac{2^{2^{n-1}}+1}{2^{2^{n-1}}} = \frac{2^{2^{2016}}-1}{2^{2^{2016}-1}}=\color{red}{2-\frac{2}{2^{2^{2016}}}}.\tag{3}$$